# How to build and embed correct app extension using multiple xcconfigs?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-extensions, xcconfig

I have an app with (intent) extension. Each of these targets has multiple configuration files.

For 'MyAppName' target I have:

```
Debug.xcconfig
    PRODUCT_NAME = $(inherited) Debug
    ...
Beta.xcconfig
    PRODUCT_NAME = $(inherited) β
    ...
```

For intent extension I have:

```
Debug.xcconfig
    PRODUCT_NAME = $(inherited) Intent Debug
    ...
Beta.xcconfig
    PRODUCT_NAME = $(inherited) Intent β
    ...
```

In there configuration files I also provide different bundle identifiers, code signing entitlements etc.

I am able to run the app on a device in `Debug` configuration, but as soon as I try to archive (for ad-hoc distribution) using `Beta` configuration I get an error:

```
/.../Xcode/DerivedData/MyAppName-bqreatpwtojzljfgrfobqszbpuvn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Countdown/BuildProductsPath/Beta-iphoneos/MyAppName Intent Debug.appex: No such file or directory (in target 'MyAppName' from project 'MyAppName')
```

For some reason the compiler is trying to locate `MyAppName Intent Debug.appex` and not `MyAppName Intent β.appex` as it should. If I look at `Embed App Extensions` in `Build Phases` of `MyAppName` target, I can see there entry `MyAppName Intent Debug.appex ...in build/Debug-iphoneos`.

How should I build and embed correct app extension? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happend to me.

I don't using .xcconfig files but similar to this user-defined settings in the build settings.

replacing 'Bundle name' in the Info.plist of the Watch and App target by the same user-defined setting constant did the job for me.